# Why if statements not working as expected with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-redux, infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I'm trying to build an app which pulls data from backend with RTK Query and display that data as posts. I have successfully created RTKQ endpoint that gets data from backend with useEffect. However I want to put data in another array so that I can add more data with infinite scroll to that array but I am not able to do that.

My code is as follow. All help will be highly appreciated.

```
import { Box, Stack, Skeleton } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Post from "../components/postComponent";
import { useGetSimplesMutation } from '../services/authApi'


const Feed = () => {
    const [getSimples, { isLoading, isSuccess, data }] = useGetSimplesMutation()
    const [loadNow, setLoadNow] = useState(false)
    let simplesData = []
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleGetSimples = async () => {
            try {
                await getSimples(0).unwrap()
                if (isSuccess & !loadNow) {
                    console.log("Simples loaded")
                    simplesData = [...simplesData, ...data]
                    setLoadNow(true)
                    console.log(simplesData)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message)
            }
        }
        handleGetSimples()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Box flex={6} p={{ xs: 0, md: 2 }}>
            {isLoading && (
                <Box marginLeft={3}>
                    <Stack spacing={1} >
                        <Skeleton variant="text" height={100} />
                        <Skeleton variant="text" height={20} />
                        <Skeleton variant="text" height={20} />
                        <Skeleton variant="rectangular" height={300} />
                    </Stack>
                </Box>
            )}
            {(isSuccess && loadNow) && simplesData.map(simples => {
                return (
                    <div key={simples._id}>
                        <Post
                            userName={simples.userName}
                            dateSubmitted={simples.dateSubmitted}
                            beforePic={simples.beforePic}
                            afterPic={simples.afterPic}
                            tag={simples.tag}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </Box>
    );
};

export default Feed;
```

This Code works when I directly map data obtained from RTKQ. However when I pass data to another array in an If statement the code inside if statement does not trigger when isSuccess gets true alongwith loadNow which has default state of false. I want to add data to simplesData array when this condition is true and then setLoadNow to true so that I can render my posts.

Answer (score 0):

The line `let simplesData = []` will be re-executed every time that the component re-renders, which will wipe out whatever you have stored.

If you want to keep data across multiple renders then you need to store it in a `useState` hook.

```
const [simplesData, setSimplesData] = useState([])
```

Inside your `useEffect`, you can call `setSimplesData`, using a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to minimize the dependencies of your effect.

```
setSimplesData(prevData => [...prevData, ...data])
```

---

There are some other issues here, mainly your lack of `useEffect` dependendencies.  I think you want something like this?

```
const Feed = () => {
    const [getSimples, { isLoading, isSuccess }] = useGetSimplesMutation()
    const [loadPage, setLoadPage] = useState(0)
    const [simplesData, setSimplesData] = useState([])

    const handleEndReached = () => {
        setLoadPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
    }

    const handleReset = () => {
        setSimplesData([]);
        setLoadPage(0);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleGetSimples = async () => {
            try {
                const pageData = await getSimples(loadPage).unwrap()
                console.log(`Simples page ${loadPage} loaded`)
                setSimplesData(prevData => [...prevData, ...pageData])
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message)
            }
        }
        handleGetSimples()
    }, [loadPage]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It really looks promising and much simple. I will try this out. I am just stuck with some other issues in my app. You can check my other questions too. I will try this solution after getting those working. Thanks anyways for taking time to help.